# regexp to get data for some symbol

Tags: php, regex

I'm using

```
preg_match_all ("#Item(.*?)1\.#si", $file, $matches);
```

I want to get result like "Item 1." or

```
Item &#160;1.
```

But now i got something like "Item 405"

```
Item&#160;9B.&#160;&#160;
Item&#160;13.&#160;&#160;
```

Any suggestion?

---

Sample input

```
<TR valign="top"> 
<TD> 
<B><FONT style="font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times">Item&#160;1.&#160;&#160;</FONT></B> 
</TD> 
<TD> 


<A name='Y86310103'> 
<DIV style="margin-top: 4pt; font-size: 1pt">&nbsp;</DIV> 

<DIV align="left" style="margin-left: 0%; margin-right: 0%; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, Helvetica; color: #000000; background: transparent">
```

I want to get

```
Item&#160;1.
```

Another input example is

```
<TD WIDTH="9%" VALIGN="top" ALIGN="left"><FONT STYLE="font-family:Times New Roman"    SIZE="2"><B><U>ITEM&nbsp;1.</U></B></FONT></TD> 
<TD ALIGN="left" VALIGN="top"><FONT STYLE="font-family:Times New Roman" SIZE="2"><B>
```

I want to get

```
 ITEM&nbsp;1.
```

**Actually, I want to get the position of "item 1."** in the html file. 
There are other similar entries like "item 1a.", "item 11"

```
Item&#160;13.&#160;&#160;
Item&#160;60l
```

I don't need those information.

Thank!

Comment: What's precisely your goal ?...

Comment: Can you add some sample input and some desired output?

Comment: Bad edit. Lots of URI encoding happening there. Please take it back to spaces in the examples.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here - the pattern `Item(.*?)1\.` will match 'Item' + (any single character, optional) + '1.'. Your question is not very clear - what is it exactly that you are trying to match?

Comment: As I recall, `(.*?)` will match zero or more of any character including whitespace.

Comment: Oops, that's correct - one or more characters. So, any substring that starts with `Item` and ends with `1.`.

Comment: It's impossible that this regex matches `Item&#160;9B.&#160;&#160;`.

Comment: @Don I have tested it. Your regexp works very well. Perhaps something other is wrong in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression matches what you expect (as I understood). See it [here online in the regex tester Regexr](http://regexr.com?2ufis).

This is a useful tool to develop and test regular expressions, I think it helps you with your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regular expression:

```
"#Item(&\#160;|\s)1\.#si"
```

Change "1" to what you really are searching for - perhaps you can tell us more about this.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$file = <<< EOF
<TR valign="top"> 
<TD> 
<B><FONT style="font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times">Item&#160;1.&#160;&#160;</FONT></B> 
</TD> 
<TD> 
<A name='Y86310103'> 
<DIV style="margin-top: 4pt; font-size: 1pt">&nbsp;</DIV> 
<DIV align="left" style="margin-left: 0%; margin-right: 0%; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, Helvetica; color: #000000; background: transparent"> 
EOF;

preg_match_all('/(Item)(?:&.*?)?;(\w+)/i', $file, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$match = $matches[1][0]." ". $matches[2][0];
echo $match; // echo's "Item 9B"
```